# SCP files in a SSH tunnel, Using Fabric

Tags: python, ssh, fabric

I've already did some release scripts with Fabric, but now the task is over my competencies.

I need to transfert with SCP a tar ball from A to C using a ssh tunnel passing by B.

I can test connections via SSH manually to see if A see B, and if B see C, and everything is fine.

I've tried the stuff on this 2 link:

https://gist.github.com/856179

https://gist.github.com/2760477

But in one case, I'm never prompted to enter a password, so it's timing out, and the other one prompted for password, but timeout when I try a basic command like "uname".

Does anyone already faced something like this ? Or have clues / hints ?

Comment: I'm trying with the /ssh/config file. I can do the SCP from local to remote without problem, but I can't execute commands on the remote server. It's timing out trying to connect :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would perhaps be to push the file to B temporarily, then send a script to B which pushes it to C?

Comment: Well I've finally done something like that. I've been able to send the package on C using ~/ssh/configs to setup the tunnel, and then on C, deploy the package.